# Cassandra insertion: InvalidQueryException: Invalid null value in condition for column

Tags: http, cassandra, dropwizard

Hi I'm starting working with Cassandra, I'm trying to insert data into Cassandra table using this code in Java in REST server created by DropWizard

```
    public int insertqueueid(Datafilter data) throws UnknownHostException 
    {
    PreparedStatement prep = defaultSession.prepare("insert into queueid (queueid, filter, nom, date) values (?,?,?,?)");
    BoundStatement bound = prep.bind(data.getQueued(),data.getFilter(),getName(), new Date()) ;
    defaultSession.execute(bound);
    return 0 ;
    }
```

But it gives me this error :

> ERROR [2017-07-03 23:45:57,514] io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.LoggingExceptionMapper: Error handling a request: 5d2d169dd71c2520
>   ! com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Invalid null value in condition for column queueid
>   ! at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:136)
>   ! at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:179)
>   ! at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:177)

What do you think, it's the problem ?
Sorry for bad language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the error it looks like NULL value is being passed to the queueid column. I assume it's the partition key of the table and you can't pass NULL for that column.

Please check the data and fix it accordingly.

Comment: yes you're right, the request i did was sending NULL values, I fixed it , thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it is Rest call please add `@RequestBody` in the method as follows.

```
public int insertqueueid(@RequestBody Datafilter data) throws UnknownHostException
```

Comment: @dilsingi, sir I dont have any column which are null my source data still I am getting the error..................................................ERROR QueryExecutor:72 - Failed to execute: com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.RichBoundStatement@397a85f3
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Invalid null value in condition for column fiscal_year
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:136)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet